# Tag special days in plotly diagram

Tags: python, plotly

I am using [Plotly API](https://plot.ly/python/) to draw line charts from a dataset in python. For example I have this dataset from the year 2018.

[image: 2018]

Now I want to check weather the weekend days have higher demand in contrast to the weekdays. My goal is to mark the lines in the diagram for saturday and sunday. 
Does Plotly provide methods to do this? If not, is there any easy method to achieve this?

Comment: You can iterate through the days and then make a color list based on the conditions you have and then use that color list to color the trace

Comment: @SreeramTP can you give an example how to do this, I don´t quite follow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a marker plot and then overlay a line plot to get the desired output where the marker plot must be passed with a list of colors that is made based on the condition.

To get a clear picture see the below codes,

```
# make a dummy time data

x_values = pd.date_range(start=pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01'), end=pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01'), freq='1 D')

# making a random time series
y_values = np.random.randn(len(x_values))

# making color list
# red if the day is saturday or sunday else green

colors = ['red' if int(pd.Timestamp(d).weekday()) >= 5 else 'green' for d in x_values]

# make the plot

trace_0 = go.Scatter(
    x=x_values,
    y=y_values,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        color = colors
    )
)

trace_1 = go.Scatter(
    x=x_values,
    y=y_values,
    mode='lines',
    marker=dict(
        color = 'black'
    )
)

layout = dict(
    title='Time Series with Rangeslider',
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(count=1,
                     label='1m',
                     step='month',
                     stepmode='backward'),
                dict(count=6,
                     label='6m',
                     step='month',
                     stepmode='backward'),
                dict(step='all')
            ])
        ),
        rangeslider=dict(
            visible = True
        ),
        type='date'
    )
)

fig = {
    'data': [trace_0, trace_1],
    'layout': layout,
}

py.iplot(fig, filename='Plot')
```

Output plot

[image]

I have also implemented a range slider, if that is not needed edit it out from the layout.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped